# Is the similar pronunciation of 上班, 办公 and 工作 just a coincidence?

Tags: pronunciation, etymology

Three important words when talking about work are

- 上班 (shàng bān, to go to work)
- 办公 (bàn gōng, to work [esp. in an office])
- 工作 (gōng zuò, job / work)

This can be confusing for beginners - I often get them mixed up because the pronunciations are similar, even though the symbols are completely different.

Is there are reason for the similar pronunciation of 班 and 办, respectively 公 and 工? Or is it basically just a coincidence?

Comment: It is just coincidence.

Comment: An interesting observation though.

Comment: I think you need to ask yourself how similar they really are. It's essentially one syllable out of two and the tone is different (except for 公/工, which clearly don't mean the same thing). I agree that it's coincidence, I just want to point out that with very lax standards for "similar", anything can look related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a coincidence. I haven't notice it until I see your question :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's a coincidence. The characters are completely unrelated.

---

**办 ban4** means "to do, to handle", and it's a [phono-semantic compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Phono-semantic_compound_characters) where the 力 part (strength) conveys the meaning, and the two dots at the sides are a simplification of 辛 (xin1). *But* the phonetic part when doubled is pronounced bian4. Compare the simplified characters 辩 （as in 辩论）and 辨 （as in 辨别）

---

**班 ban1** means "class, team", and it's a [compound ideograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Compound_ideographs) composed of two 玉 （jade）and 刀 （knife）.

> *To 刀 cut up 玉 pieces of jade and bestow the halfs as rank insignia upon feudatory chiefs* (Karlgren)

---

**公 gong1** alone means "official duties" or "public affairs", and is （if I'm not mistaken) also a compound ideograph, from 八 and 厶.

> *The right 八 division of 厶 private things* (Karlgren)

---

**工 gong1** means "work" and is instead a [pictogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Pictograms) of an axe (a carpenter square, according to Karlgren). (See picture)

[image]

Comment: That description of 公 is not correct unfortunately (it’s actually a picture of a clay jar, and is the original form of 瓮). In general it’s better to trust paleographers over linguists for tracing glyph origins - paleographers have a higher focus on primary evidence.

Comment: @dROOOze so is it the consensus now in academia that paleographers are more *correct* sources than linguists? Do you have any links? I’m not in front of my computer atm

Comment: Put it this way - paleographers will not only look at the primary sources of text (oracle bone, bronze inscriptions, bamboo strips), but they will also use linguistics as a tool to determine glyphs and the words they represent, and will engage in readings of classical literature. The most famous works on Chinese linguistics are now *outdated* - apart from Baxter and Sagart's work (2014) which reverses the process by including paleography in their linguistic models, the rest are a few decades out of date in terms of the latest research.

Comment: This particular description of 公 comes straight from 說文, and is what people normally resort to if they don't have any better research to fall back on. Since linguists are normally more out-of-date than paleographers in models of writing and the words they represent, their description of glyph origins are much more likely to be out of date too.

Comment: @dROOOze I see, that’s interesting. I would like to do some more research. Can you give me any titles that you deem particularly representative of this modern paleographic approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just a coincidence.
What you found is similar pronunciation of 上班, 办公 and 工作 in **Mandarin**, not similar pronunciation of 上班, 办公 and 工作 in **Chinese**.

If you get this point, you will realize that these three words appeared before Mandarin was created.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Chinese Language Stack Exchange. I find your explanation a bit confusing, especially since you don't transcribe the pronunciation. "Mandarin" (官话) refers to a dialect group spoken predominantly in North-East China; "Chinese" is a broader group that includes Mandarin. Perhaps one of the two terms you used needs to be replaced with "Standard Chinese" (普通话)?